# how can I include the dll in already created .exe

Tags: c#, dll, installation

i am working windows forms application project ,i am created setup for my project and installed in to my client's system.now i added new dll in my project and i like to add that dll to my client's system without creating new setup.how can i do this,pls provide articles for this.Is click one deployment mechanism help for my problem.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Send the DLL to your client** and ask him to drop it into `\bin` directory of your application install directory.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into ClickOnce deployment? It might be the solution you are looking for.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t71a733d(VS.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

enter code hereEasiest way is to send your client the dll and ask him to copy to where you want it to be copied. But if you dont want him to do all that you can create a batch file as described below and send it to him and ask him to execute it.
You want to copy the DLL from your machine to your client's machine is it. You can create a simple batch file and execute the file. You can use the following command

```
xcopy /Y /R /Q /K "Sample.dll" %WPINSTDIR%
```

where Sample.dll would be your DLL name and WPINSTDIR is the installation directory.

Comment: how do i create that batch file

Comment: Yes true just write the above command in a notepad file and save it as name.bat. Send this to your client or make a .exe using Winzip and send it and ask him to run it.